# Google Cloud Dataflow TextIO write to .gz file?

Tags: google-bigquery, google-cloud-storage, google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam

How can we create a compressed file in GCS through Google dataflow jobs?

I am not able to specify compression type. If the feature is not already present, is there a cleaner way to output to a compressed file from Google BigQuery's query?

Answer (score 6):

You'll want to use TextIO to write to files (for an overview of all the built-in I/O transform, look [here](https://beam.apache.org/documentation/io/built-in/)).

You can see an example in the code [here](https://github.com/apache/beam/blob/master/sdks/java/core/src/main/java/org/apache/beam/sdk/io/TextIO.java):

```
PCollection<String> lines = ...;
lines.apply(TextIO.write().to("/path/to/file.txt")
  .withSuffix(".txt")
  .withWritableByteChannelFactory(FileBasedSink.CompressionType.GZIP));
```

**Edit:** you can also export a table from BigQuery to a gzipped file directly from the GUI:[image]

Comment: Unfortunately, Google's Dataflow doesn't provide .withWritableByteChannelFactory()

Comment: Which SDK are you using exactly? Updated the code above btw.

Comment: com.google.cloud.dataflow:google-cloud-dataflow-java-sdk-all:1.9.0

Comment: In the [docs for Dataflow 1.x](https://cloud.google.com/dataflow/model/text-io#reading-from-compressed-text-files) I found this: _"TextIO does not currently support writing to compressed files."_ To the best of my knowledge, Dataflow 1.9 is not actively developed anymore, so you'll have to resort to [2.0.0](https://cloud.google.com/dataflow/release-notes/release-notes-java-2) or use the BigQuery GUI (see above).